# Compare two files write only the first match to a third (new) file

Tags: python

I'm comparing two files and in each file I have lists of combinations.

File A looks like this: 
1, 2, 3 
1, 2, 4 
1, 2, 5 
1, 2, 6

File B looks like this: 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5 
1, 2, 3, 4, 6 
1, 2, 3, 4, 7 
1, 2, 4, 5, 6

When a line in File A first matches three numbers from a line in File B. I want to write that first matched line from File B to a File C (the new file), but only if the line hasn't already been written to File C.

So with the example files above it would be: 
first match for 1, 2, 3 is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 does not exist in File C. Write 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 to File C. 
first match for 1, 2, 4 is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 does exist in File C. Do nothing. 
first match for 1, 2, 5 is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 does exist in File C. Do nothing. 
first match for 1, 2, 6 is 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 
 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 does not exist in File C. Write 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 to File C.

The desired result is: 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5 
1, 2, 3, 4, 6

What I have been trying below is to compare files and then print the line from File B to File C. But I'm lost when trying to get only the first match for each line to write to File C and to not write any duplicate lines in File C. Any insight or suggests are greatly appreciated.

```
with open('FileA.txt', 'r') as k:
    h = k.read().splitlines()

with open('FileB.txt') as f, open('FileC.txt', 'w') as o:
    for fivecombo in f:
        breakfivecombo = (fivecombo.split())
        for threecombo in h:
            breakthreecombo = (threecombo.split())
            minmatch = 3
            currentmatch = 0
            for splitfive in breakfivecombo:
                for splitthree in breakthreecombo:
                    if splitfive == splitthree:
                        currentmatch+=1
                        if currentmatch == minmatch:
                            o.writelines(fivecombo)
```

Comment: Can we assume that the two files are sorted? If not, can we sort them?

Comment: Both files are sorted.

Comment: are there repeated numbers present in the sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check subset by method `issubset` of set

```py
from itertools import repeat

def convert(text):
    return list(map(set, map(str.split, text.split('\n'), repeat(', '))))

def deconvert(sequence):
    return '\n'.join(', '.join(sorted(item)) for item in sequence)

# the content of File B and File C
a = '1, 2, 3\n1, 2, 4\n1, 2, 5\n1, 2, 6'
b = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5\n1, 2, 3, 4, 6\n1, 2, 3, 4, 7\n1, 2, 4, 5, 6'

a_int = convert(a)
b_int = convert(b)

c_int = []

for i in a_int:
    for j in b_int:
        if i.issubset(j):
            if j not in c_int:
                c_int.append(j)
            break
# The content for file C
print(deconvert(c_int))
```